# import errors in pytest unable to run tests

Tags: python, django, import, pytest, pytest-django

I'm having a problem with my imports in my django project, I'm trying to run my first tests in pytest but I'm getting import errors:

```
name = 'tasks', package = None

    def import_module(name, package=None):
        """Import a module.
    
        The 'package' argument is required when performing a relative import. It
        specifies the package to use as the anchor point from which to resolve the
        relative import to an absolute import.
    
        """
        level = 0
        if name.startswith('.'):
            if not package:
                msg = ("the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative "
                       "import for {!r}")
                raise TypeError(msg.format(name))
            for character in name:
                if character != '.':
                    break
                level += 1
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
E       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tasks'

/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126: ModuleNotFoundError
================================================================================= short test summary info =================================================================================
FAILED core_apps/tracker/tests/test_tasks.py::FetchAndStoreVehicleModelsTest::test_existing_models_are_updated - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tasks'
FAILED core_apps/tracker/tests/test_tasks.py::FetchAndStoreVehicleModelsTest::test_new_models_are_created - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tasks'
```

this is my project diretory tree

```
core_apps
├── __init__.py
├── tracker
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── services
│   │   ├── coopart.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── tasks.py
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── test_tasks.py
│   └── views.py
└── users
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── forms.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── managers.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

this is import in test_tasks.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch

from core_apps.tracker.models import VehicleModel
from core_apps.tracker.tasks import fetch_and_store_vehicle_makes


class FetchAndStoreVehicleModelsTest(TestCase):
    @patch('tasks.CopartIaaiService.get_values')
    def test_new_models_are_created(self, mock_get_values):
        mock_get_values.return_value = {
            "result": [
                {"id": 1, "model": "Model1", "model_slug": "model1", "make_id": 1},
                {"id": 2, "model": "Model2", "model_slug": "model2", "make_id": 2},
            ]
        }

        fetch_and_store_vehicle_makes()

        self.assertEqual(VehicleModel.objects.count(), 2)
        self.assertEqual(VehicleModel.objects.get(make_id=1).model, "Model1")
        self.assertEqual(VehicleModel.objects.get(make_id=2).model, "Model2")

    @patch('tasks.CopartIaaiService.get_values')
    def test_existing_models_are_updated(self, mock_get_values):
        VehicleModel.objects.create(model="Old Model1", model_slug="old_model1", make_id=1)
        VehicleModel.objects.create(model="Old Model2", model_slug="old_model2", make_id=2)

        mock_get_values.return_value = {
            "result": [
                {"id": 1, "model": "New Model1", "model_slug": "new_model1", "make_id": 1},
                {"id": 2, "model": "New Model2", "model_slug": "new_model2", "make_id": 2},
            ]
        }

        fetch_and_store_vehicle_makes()

        self.assertEqual(VehicleModel.objects.count(), 2)
        self.assertEqual(VehicleModel.objects.get(make_id=1).model, "New Model1")
        self.assertEqual(VehicleModel.objects.get(make_id=2).model, "New Model2")
```

this is task.py  file :

```
from core.celery import app
from core_apps.tracker.models import VehicleMake
from core_apps.tracker.services.coopart import CopartIaaiService


@app.task
def fetch_and_store_vehicle_makes():
    service = CopartIaaiService()
    vehicle_make_data = service.get_values("get-makes")

    updated_count = 0
    created_count = 0

    for vehicle_make_data in vehicle_make_data['result']:
        if not vehicle_make_data['make']:
            continue
        vehicle_make, created = VehicleMake.objects.update_or_create(
            id=vehicle_make_data['id'],
            defaults={
                'name': vehicle_make_data['make'],
                'slug': vehicle_make_data['make_slug'],
            }
        )
        if created:
            created_count += 1
        else:
            updated_count += 1

    return {"updated": updated_count, "created": created_count}
```

I'm I missing something here? My ide even prompted me this import ... This is why I thing it should work. Maybe there are some additional settings in pytest? Can somebody help me with it please?

Answer (score 0):

Try running your code as a module from the CLI: python -m pytest